# TileMill fails to load Europe data from PostGIS. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, tilemill, mapbox, osm2pgsql

**The Problem:**

Using [OSM-Bright](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright) in combination with an imported (`osm2psql`) Europe shapefile, tiles won't load unless I have 2-3 layers active (of the total of 29). I don't have this problem with an imported Netherlands or Amsterdam shapefile. So I'm assuming it has something to do with the sheer amount of data that gets returned by the queries?

**My Setup:**

I am running [TileMill](https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill) with [OSM-Bright](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright) on an `Amazon EC2 c3.2xlarge`:

`8 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz 15.8GB RAM / linux ubuntu 14.04 trusty / TileMill 0.10.2`

The only changed settings of Postgres I have done are:

`work_mem = 2MB maintenance_work_mem = 32MB`

**Detailed description & what I have tried:**

When loading the map, it seems as though the query times out. I have tried making a swapfile and monitoring memory when opening the project. The swapfile doesn't get touched and the memory gets drained to ~1% and stays there.

I won't get any errors when it 'times out' (tiles get the 'image not available' icon), not in the client interface, and when running TileMill via SSH there are no errors in the output. Very rarely I get a `"PostGIS connection: null"` error in the TileMill interface. When this happens, I get `{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }` in the Tilemill log.

**Screenshot:**
[image: empty tiles]

Is there anything I can do to optimize the loading of the queries so I can work with the huge Europe dataset? Or is there any good practice in handling such large datasets with TileMill & OSM-Bright?

PS. for reference, this is the script I used while importing Europe into postgres (I don't know if it is relevant):

`sudo osm2pgsql -c -G -C 14000 --cache-strategy sparse -U postgres -d osm /data/downloads/europe-shapefile/europe-latest.osm.pbf`

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem and I ended up using adopted way_area size clauses.
By default they seemed to be too small for me. So when zooming out it would fetch so many very small polygons that that was too much data to transfer. So basically you don't display too small polygons when being zoomed out. You have to try and error until you have the best results for your need.

Next thing I did was to simplify polygons. When you zoom out, f.e. the border of a country doesn't need to be that detailed. You can use Postgis (ST_simplifiy) for that task. That again helps to keep transferred datasizes smaller (a lot smaller).

Those two things helped A LOT getting my map to work again with a huge dataset.

I'd be interested to know what else you did to improve the rendering performance of your map?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for helping me! Glad to see that I'm not the only one having this problem. Could you give an example how you wrote the way_area size clauses? I don't fully understand the imported table columns yet, what unit are the way_area sizes? Is that square meters or anything similar?

Comment: I am not sure which unit they are in... I found that: `For "geometry" type area is in SRID units. For "geography" area is in square meters.`... But what I did (I am a non GIS guy), I searched for something I know how big it was (Like a lake... compare to Wikipedia) and see how big the way_area is. Then start adopting your way_area clauses...

Hope it helps...

Comment: Ah that is a good idea to get a relative sense of what the value means. I will fiddle with it to optimize it. Could you give an example of a query where you simplify the geometry? I wrapped `ST_Simplify` around `way` in my query: `SELECT ST_Simplify(way), way_area AS area, COALESCE(landuse, leisure, "natural", highway, amenity, tourism) AS type` but I get the `Postgis Plugin: ERROR:  function st_simplify(geometry) does not exist` error. Thanks for helping again, I am a mobile developer by trade and a bit new to GIS also.

Comment: write `SELECT ST_Simplify(way) as way`  so the `as way` is missing :)

Comment: just out of curiosity... what are you developing? Cause I am a mobile developer as well and the GIS stuff is the stuff that I had to learn for a new app :)

Comment: Thanks, missed the `as way` indeed. Cool that you're a mobile dev too :), the company I work for is going to switch from a Netherlands-only mapping company to OSM (for international map data), so we have to host and do everything ourselves. I am in charge of that project. It doesn't have much to do with our apps (except support for offline-maps), so I am treading on new territory.

Comment: I have been experimenting with the `way_area` threshold a bit for the water and landuse layers, but I am still running into some problems. The map now loads for low zoom levels (0-6) after a long time, but any higher than that gets me a timeout on Postgres again. Could you tell me how you optimized more than changing the `way_area` property and simplifying? Did you make separate layers for `landuse/water` or was setting the `way_area` property and simplifying the geometry enough?

Comment: Look at your postgres DB processes. See what's taking so long... If it's the ST_Simplify(way) you might want to pre-calculate them... Or if it's not the calculation of ST_Simplify(way) but the data transfered, then try to use more aggressive simplification... When zoomed out to 0-6 the shapes can be super simplified i guess...
Landuse and water are separate layers in my map yes. But that was the default of OSM_Bright?!?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try that, accept your answer and report back when I get it to work. OSM-Bright has landuse and water as 6 seperate layers by default indeed (landuse,landuse_gen0,landuse_gen1 for example).

Comment: Sure.. keep me updated :)

Comment: just out of curiosity... did you get your map to work? did you find any other useful tricks to tweak your performance?

Comment: I didn't answer this question yet, because Europe unfortunately still doesn't work. When it does, I will answer this question with what made it work.

However, I made a smaller subset work by applying some tricks. Firstly I upgraded my hardware. It seemed my machine was very quickly running out of memory, so I upgraded from 15 to 64GB. This made the map atleast work in some cases. 

Then I noticed that OSMBright sets extends for the map to basically the whole world when you make the project. I recalculated proper extends per layer (click remove cache and save). This gave another huge boost.

Comment: Furthermore, I edited our style files with many way_area checks to reduce results. Also, I made alot of different layers for landuse and water, for each 3 zoomlevels I made a new query that had more or less results to save memory and transfer. This helped too. ST_Simplify however, was too expensive for my machine to render, basically hanging the process. I will update when I get Europe to work (could take some time because we can atm comprimise to have only a few countries instead of the whole continent). If you find other ways to improve rendering please share! :)

Comment: We created a separate table for the gen0, gen1. So it only has to calculate once and you just sacrifice a bit of HDD space but save a lot of CPU time when exporting/styling your map... We are also playing around again with our map. If I find new insights I'll keep you informed.

Comment: Thank you, please do! :) Good idea, using seperate tables! We should try that too